# Me da este error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'palillos' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

``Estoy aprendiendo, aun que declaro palillos como una variable global pero al usarla en un for dentro de una función me da ese error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'palillos' referenced before assignment.
Y no entiendo por que me da ese error.

```
# Creamos la cantidad de palillos con que se va a jugar 

palillos = random.randint(16, 23)
while palillos >= 0:    
    def crear_palillos():       
        os.system("cls")
        for i in range(3):
            print()
            for p in range(palillos):
                print("  ◘  ")

    if i >= 3:
        palillos = 0

    crear_palillos()
```

Comment: hacía tiempo que no veia cosas tan raras en programación. Por qué tienes un `def` para crear una función dentro un while loop? las funciones deberían crearse una única vez. Deberías crear la función en algún lugar externo al while loop y simplemente llamarla desde dentro cuando la necesites.

Answer (score 0):

el while tiene el propósito de que hasta que los palillos no queden 0 siga dibujando los palillos que van quedando, entiendo que sin estar el programa completo es difícil de ver el fallo que tengo, pero de todas maneras gracias ya lo he arreglado después de mucho pensar.
saludos

Comment: Ayudaría mucho al contexto de tu solución que agregues como lo solucionaste